# Only display field name records are not showing

Tags: apex, visualforce

vf page is

```
<apex:page standardController="QuickCase__c" extensions="qs">
<apex:pageBlock title="Nominate user">
<apex:pageblockTable value="{!QuickCase__c}" var="quick">
<apex:column value="{!quick.Name}"/>


</apex:pageblockTable>

</apex:pageBlock>

</apex:page>
```

class

```
public with sharing class qs {
    List<Quickcase__c> Quick = new list<Quickcase__c>();
    public qs(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {


    }
    public qs  ()
{
Quick = [select id ,Name from Quickcase__c limit 5];
}


}
```

Comment: Hi Niranjan, welcome to SFSE. Pleases take a moment to visit the [help], scroll through the [tour], and read [ask]. What is it you are trying to accomplish? How does the observed behavior fall short? It is very difficult to help you when you offer so little description. The more specific you are, the better chance someone will help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your code in following way.

**Visualforce**

```
<apex:page standardController="QuickCase__c" extensions="qs" action="{!init}">
    <apex:pageBlock title="Nominate user">
        <apex:pageblockTable value="{!Quick}" var="qk">
        <apex:column value="{!qk.Name}"/>
        </apex:pageblockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

**Controller**

```
public with sharing class qs 
{
    public List<Quickcase__c> Quick {get;set;}
    public qs(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

    }
    public void init()
    {
        Quick = [select id ,Name from Quickcase__c limit 5];
    }
}
```

> Note: following changes have been made.

1. Rather than using second no argument constructor, changed it to `init()` method which is getting called from `apex:page` action.
2. Instead of using `List<Quickcase__c> Quick = new list<Quickcase__c>();`, following public getter-setter used: `public List<Quickcase__c> Quick {get;set;}`
3. You have incorrectly used `<apex:pageblockTable value="{!QuickCase__c}"`, value should expect `List` of records.

I should suggest you go through trailheads to learn Visualforce.

Comment: `init` is not necessary, and in fact, I would argue not a best practice. Objects should generally be initialized in their constructor.

Comment: is that be a good practice to use SOQL query in constructor, pls let me know

Comment: For a Visualforce controller or extension, we should use queries in the constructor if we need to. We shouldn't use them if we don't need to, of course, but there's no reason why we should use an action method for the sole purpose of writing a query. Action methods are typically reserved for callouts, DML operations, and redirects, none of which you can do in a constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You should initialize your extension in its one-parameter constructor. Also, you can't bind to the standard object to iterate over the query you've written, but instead need a public variable to bind to. The following changes would be appropriate for your code:

---

```
<apex:page standardController="QuickCase__c" extensions="qs">
  <apex:pageBlock title="Nominate user">
    <apex:pageblockTable value="{!quickCaseList}" var="quick">
      <apex:column value="{!quick.Name}"/>
    </apex:pageblockTable>
  </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

---

```
public with sharing class qs {
  public List<Quickcase__c> quickCaseList { get; set; }
  public qs(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
    quickCaseList = [select Name from Quickcase__c limit 5];
  }
}
```